# command not found in C++ Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my C++ Makefile i run on my UNIX :

```
# This is a Makefile for the SocNetwork project 
CCC = g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g 
CXXLINK = $(CCC) 
OBJS = Message.o Date.o main.o SocialNetwork.o User.o 
RM enter code here= rm -f 
all: SocNetwork 
# Creating the executable (SocNetwork) 
SocNetwork: $(OBJS) 
        $(CXXLINK) -o SocNetwork $(OBJS) 
# Creating object files using default rules 
Date.o: Date.C Date.H 
main.o: main.C SocialNetwork.H User.H defs.H Date.H Message.H 
Message.o: Message.C Message.H defs.H 
SocialNetwork.o: SocialNetwork.C SocialNetwork.H User.H defs.H Date.H Message.H 
User.o: User.C User.H defs.H Date.H Message.H 
# Cleaning old files before new make 
clean: 
        $(RM) SocNetwork screen_test *.o *.bak *~ "#"* core
```

When I run the makefile in UNIX i get:

```
./makefile: line 2: CCC: command not found
./makefile: line 3: CXXFLAGS: command not found
./makefile: line 4: CCC: command not found
./makefile: line 4: CXXLINK: command not found
./makefile: line 5: OBJS: command not found
./makefile: line 6: RM: command not found
./makefile: line 7: all:: command not found
./makefile: line 9: OBJS: command not found
./makefile: line 9: SocNetwork:: command not found
./makefile: line 10: CXXLINK: command not found
./makefile: line 10: OBJS: command not found
./makefile: line 10: -o: command not found
./makefile: line 12: Date.o:: command not found
./makefile: line 13: main.o:: command not found
./makefile: line 14: Message.o:: command not found
./makefile: line 15: SocialNetwork.o:: command not found
./makefile: line 16: User.o:: command not found
./makefile: line 18: clean:: command not found
./makefile: line 19: RM: command not found
./makefile: line 19: SocNetwork: command not found
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my makefile? there is no problem with Tabs, i checked. 
Thanx!!!

Comment: If you're going to try that, use a shebang on line 1 of your makefile: `#!/usr/bin/make -f`.

Comment: Oh my loving God...... >>.<<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run the `make` command, which will pick up the `makefile` and do its stuff. It looks like you are trying to execute the makefile itself.

Comment: god! Your'e right! TNX!!!